# Cannot print dictionary list after quizzing user

Tags: python, list, dictionary

After quizzing a user on a dictionary of states and their capitals with the keys being the state abbreviations, I cannot seem to print out the full dictionary:

```
# Initialize the state capitals dictionary
NUM_STATES = 6

def main():

    state_caps = state_cap_dic()

    # Initial variables to keep count of the number of right/wrong answers
    correct = 0
    incorrect = 0

    # Quiz the user.
    for count in range(NUM_STATES):
        state, capital = state_caps.popitem()   ## get random entry from dic

        # print statement for them to enter their input
        print('What is the capital of ', state, '? ', end=' ')
        response = input()

        # is the user right or wrong if/else clause with .lower function?
        if response.lower() == capital.lower():
            correct += 1
            print('Correct!')
        else:
            incorrect += 1
            print('Incorrect Broski!')

    # Display the results
    print('Correct responses:', correct)
    print('Incorrect responses:', incorrect)

# State_cap_dictionary function builds a dictionary of
# US states and their capitals. Function returns a reference to dictionary

    for key in state_caps:
        print(key,state_caps[key])



def state_cap_dic():

    sc = {'Alabama' : 'Montgomery',
          'Alaska' : 'Juneau',
          'Arizona' : 'Phoenix',
          'Arkansas' : 'Little Rock',
          'California' : 'Sacramento',
          'Colorado' : 'Denver'}

    return sc


    states = {'Alabama' : ['AL','Montgomery', 'yellowhammer'],
             "Alaska" : ['AK','Juneau','willow'],
             'Arizona': ['AZ','Bogart','cactus wren'],
             'Arkansas' : ['AR','Little Rock','mockingbird'],
             'California' : ['CA','Sacramento','quail'],
             'Colorado' : ['CO','Denver','lark bunting']
           }
    print(states['Alabama'])

    title = 'Alabama'

    show_states(states)  ## call show_states function with the arg. states            

def show_states(states):

    ## processing the dictionary with a "for" loop
    print('\nSTATE\t\tABBREVIATION\tSTATE CAPITAL\tSTATE BIRD')
    print()

    for item in states:
        print(item + '\t\t' + states[item][0] + '\t\t' + states[item][1])

main()
```

I just want the states and their respective abbreviations capitals and state birds, I'm guessing it's just the syntax that's wrong?

EDIT: Output should return the list of states and their capitals (sc) or better yet the states dictionary i tried creating with the state bird. There is no error message that occurs when the quiz ends, the program just simply ends there. This is in Python 3 just to note!

Comment: What do you mean you can't? You need to add the error you get.

Comment: no error pops up, the call to print the dictionary out (states in this case, or even just sc) doesn't work, after the quiz it just ends and goes back to the interpreter

Comment: There's a few issues here, but the first one that pop out is that `state_cap_dic()` doesn't actually return anything.

Comment: @Jfalcone which code you say is not working? You need to include what you got as output and what you expected instead.

Comment: if you run the program with just the code ending at the return sc and then ending the main() function, the quiz works just fine. I would just like to either print out that sc list or the full states list with the abbreviations and state bird (i'd be fine with just printing out that sc list though)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is the use of the [popitem()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.popitem) method which removes the instance from the dictionary. By running a cycle trough all the states you end up with an empty dictionary.

You should try to use the [random](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) module to pick up the states. I believe that the random.choice(state_caps.keys()) function will work in python2 as random state selector.

Comment: ahh this is python 3 I should probably put that in as a note when I first post, thank you for reminding of such things